# Imager - HTTP status “401” error while generating transform

Tags: plugin-imager

When I uploaded the website to a new server, some transforms don't generate and throw an exception instead:

`HTTP status “401” encountered while attempting to download “https://domain.com/web/uploads/image.png”`

I'm not really sure what causes this - some images cause this problem and some don't. All are from the same asset source.

Comment: Status 401 means it's unauthorized. Are all the images in `uploads/` directly? Or are some images located inside a sub-folder? It seems that they have the wrong permissions, did you already check that?

Comment: All images are in subfolders of uploads actually. All files hav esame permission (displayed by filezilla) - adfrw (0644). All directories have - flcdmpe (0755). So permissions seem to be OK. And yet some images cause this error and some not.